# grails fields plugin widget String is escaped

Tags: grails, field, scaffolding

I am using Grails 2.3.7 and Fields plugin version 1.3

With this in my _field.gsp under _fields folder

```
<%@ page defaultCodec="html" %>
    <div class="control-group ${invalid ? 'error' : ''}">
            <label class="control-label" for="${property}">${required? '*' : '' } ${label}
            </label>
        ${widget}
    </div>
```

The input tags are getting escaped and hence showing up as Strings instead of being rendered as html components.

I tried decoding them using widget.decodeHTML() but doesnt seem to make a difference.

Is there any other configuration I am missing to make this work?

Comment: Does it work if you remove `<%@ page defaultCodec="html" %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails 2.3.x you can use the `raw()` method in views to specify that your output is safe and should not be escaped. In your case:

```
${raw(widget)}
```

[This blog post by Mr. Haki](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html) should be helpful.